# Is there any good layer opacity instrument in folium?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

I'm trying to use folium library for python 3 to achieve some beatiful maps. I have a set of circles that overlap, and I wan't to draw all of them simultaneously in such way that background map is still visible. The problem is that I **do not** want the overlapping areas to be less transparent.

Here's code example:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location = [60.25, 24.8], zoom_start = 12)

circle_centers = [[60.2, 24.9], [60.2, 24.875], [60.2, 24.85], [60.2, 24.825], [60.2, 24.8]]

for center in circle_centers:
    folium.Circle(center, radius = 1250, fill = True, fill_opacity = 0.5, opacity = 0.5).add_to(m)

m
```

This code results in the following:

[Code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKbUt.jpg)

What I want instead is that all area covered by all circles together has the same opacity, like this:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BxXg.jpg)

The problem is that I couldn't find any way to do so. I tried using feature group from folium, adding all the circles there with fill_opacity = 1 & opacity = 1 and then somehow setting the whole feature group opacity to 0.5, but it didn't work out for some reason. I'd be glad if someone could tell me if it's possible and how to achieve this.